# Python asyncio: Queue.join() finishes only when exception are not raised, why? (context: writting an async map function)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've been trying to write an async version of the `map` function in Python for doing IO.

To do that, I'm using a queue with a producer/consumer.

At first it seems to be working well, but only without exceptions.

In particular, if I use `queue.join()`, it works well when no exceptions, but blocks in case of exception.
If I use `gather(*tasks)`, it works well when there is an exception, but blocks if not.

So it only finished sometimes, and I just don't understand why.

Here is the code I've implemented:

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import Queue
from typing import Iterable, Callable, TypeVar

Input = TypeVar("Input")
Output = TypeVar("Output")
STOP = object()


def parallel_map(func: Callable[[Input], Output], iterable: Iterable[Input]) -> Iterable[Output]:
    """
    Parallel version of `map`, backed by asyncio.
    Only suitable to do IO in parallel (not for CPU intensive tasks, otherwise it will block).
    """

    number_of_parallel_calls = 9

    async def worker(input_queue: Queue, output_queue: Queue) -> None:
        while True:
            data = await input_queue.get()
            try:
                output = func(data)
                # Simulate an exception:
                # raise RuntimeError("")
                output_queue.put_nowait(output)
            finally:
                input_queue.task_done()

    async def group_results(output_queue: Queue) -> Iterable[Output]:
        output = []
        while True:
            item = await output_queue.get()
            if item is not STOP:
                output.append(item)
            output_queue.task_done()
            if item is STOP:
                break
        return output

    async def procedure() -> Iterable[Output]:
        # First, produce a queue of inputs
        input_queue: Queue = asyncio.Queue()
        for i in iterable:
            input_queue.put_nowait(i)

        # Then, assign a pool of tasks to consume it (and also produce outputs in a new queue)
        output_queue: Queue = asyncio.Queue()
        tasks = []
        for _ in range(number_of_parallel_calls):
            task = asyncio.create_task(worker(input_queue, output_queue))
            tasks.append(task)

        # Wait for the input queue to be fully consumed (only works if no exception occurs in the tasks), blocks otherwise.
        await input_queue.join()
        # Gather tasks, only works when an exception is raised in a task, blocks otherwise
        # asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()

        # Indicate that the output queue is complete, to stop the worker
        output_queue.put_nowait(STOP)

        # Consume the output_queue, and return its data as a list
        group_results_task = asyncio.create_task(group_results(output_queue))
        await output_queue.join()
        output = await group_results_task
        return output

    return asyncio.run(procedure())

if __name__ == "__main__()":
    def my_function(x):
        return x * x

    data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(parallel_map(my_function, data))
```

I think I'm misunderstanding a *basic* but *important* with Python asyncio, but not sure what.

Comment: *In particular, if I use queue.join(), it works well when no exceptions, but blocks in case of exception.* - I cannot reproduce this behavior. I copied your code to a file, had to change `if __name__ == "__main__()"` to `if __name__ == "__main__"`, and ran it - it printed `[1, 4, 9, 16]`. Then I uncommented the `raise RuntimeError` line and ran it again - now it printed `[]`. In neither case was there any blocking. Reproduced with Python 3.7 and 3.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is, your are *NOT* catching exceptions.

From [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.join)

> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an **item is added** to the queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer coroutine **calls task_done()** to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it is complete. *When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join() unblocks*.

So `Queue` is essentially counting number of calls on `put()`, and reducing counter by 1 on every `task_done()` call. If worker stops before processing all queue, you are blocked in `Queue.join()`.

At your worker code:

```
    async def worker(input_queue: Queue, output_queue: Queue) -> None:
        while True:
            data = await input_queue.get()
            try:
                output = func(data)
                output_queue.put_nowait(output)
            finally:
                input_queue.task_done()
```

Your worker stops when it encounters *Exception*, becuase `try-finally` *only* guarantee cleanup, not actual error handling.

Therefore what is happening for your case is:

0. Each `Queue.put()` call increase internal counter, lets say we called it `n` times.
1. Workers start calling `Queue.task_done()` to decrease internal counter.
2. When encountering error, worker will stop after executing `finally` block.
3. Now if all workers stop, `Queue.task_done()` call count `n'` is `n' < n`, internal counter is still in positive value.
4. `Queue.join()` Hangs indefinitely until internal counter is 0, which never happens as all worker died.

This is a design Flaw.

---

### Additional helpful changes

There is multiple design factors to be changed for the sake of easy implementation, less prune to failure, and performance.

Do note that this is from my experience with python, so don't take this as concrete facts.

For design factors, I've made following changes:

- It's pointless if it's running `function` only, so it's better to support `coroutine` too.
- `input_queue` is guaranteed to be populated before `worker`. Checking `Queue.empty()` would be enough to determine the end of loop.
- If you start by filling `input_queue` then no need of *sentinel*, you know how long given `iterable` was, by `queue.qszie()`.
- Use `await Queue.put()` rather than `put_nowait()`, You can't be sure if `Queue` is not available at that precise timing you're putting on it.
- Keep order of input and output with extra *index* parameter, You also can't be sure about order of output with concurrent task.
- Rather than implementing fail-safe in `Exception`, put errors in result and process all queue, then simply re-raise it on user's choice.
- Use *genexp* in task spawning, `for` is not needed for this task - and `list.append` will hinder your script's performance.
- Do not import `Queue` from `asyncio`, it does not warn user enough if it's from `queue` or any other libraries with built-in `Queue` objects.
- No need to wait for `queue.join` to run `group_results` - `await` it altogether.

Function Code:

```
import asyncio


def parallel_map(func, iterable, concurrent_limit=2, raise_error=False):
    async def worker(input_queue: asyncio.Queue, output_queue: asyncio.Queue):

        while not input_queue.empty():
            idx, item = await input_queue.get()
            try:
                # Support both coroutine and function. Coroutine function I mean!
                if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
                    output = await func(item)
                else:
                    output = func(item)
                await output_queue.put((idx, output))

            except Exception as err:
                await output_queue.put((idx, err))

            finally:
                input_queue.task_done()

    async def group_results(input_size, output_queue: asyncio.Queue):
        output = {}  # using dict to remove the need to sort list

        for _ in range(input_size):
            idx, val = await output_queue.get()  # gets tuple(idx, result)
            output[idx] = val
            output_queue.task_done()

        return [output[i] for i in range(input_size)]

    async def procedure():
        # populating input queue
        input_queue: asyncio.Queue = asyncio.Queue()
        for idx, item in enumerate(iterable):
            input_queue.put_nowait((idx, item))
        
        # Remember size before using Queue
        input_size = input_queue.qsize()

        # Generate task pool, and start collecting data.
        output_queue: asyncio.Queue = asyncio.Queue()
        result_task = asyncio.create_task(group_results(input_size, output_queue))
        tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(worker(input_queue, output_queue))
            for _ in range(concurrent_limit)
        ]
        
        # Wait for tasks complete
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        
        # Wait for result fetching
        results = await result_task
        
        # Re-raise errors at once if raise_error
        if raise_error and (errors := [err for err in results if isinstance(err, Exception)]):
            # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
            raise Exception(errors)  # It never runs before assignment, safe to ignore.

        return results

    return asyncio.run(procedure())
```

Test code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random
    import time

    data = [1, 2, 3]
    err_data = [1, 'yo', 3]

    def test_normal_function(data_, raise_=False):
        def my_function(x):
            t = random.uniform(1, 2)
            print(f"Sleep {t:.3} start")

            time.sleep(t)
            print(f"Awake after {t:.3}")

            return x * x

        print(f"Normal function: {parallel_map(my_function, data_, raise_error=raise_)}\n")

    def test_coroutine(data_, raise_=False):
        async def my_coro(x):
            t = random.uniform(1, 2)
            print(f"Coroutine sleep {t:.3} start")

            await asyncio.sleep(t)
            print(f"Coroutine awake after {t:.3}")

            return x * x

        print(f"Coroutine {parallel_map(my_coro, data_, raise_error=raise_)}\n")

    # Test starts
    print(f"Test for data {data}:")
    test_normal_function(data)
    test_coroutine(data)

    print(f"Test for data {err_data} without raise:")
    test_normal_function(err_data)
    test_coroutine(err_data)

    print(f"Test for data {err_data} with raise:")
    test_normal_function(err_data, True)
    test_coroutine(err_data, True)  # this line will not run, but works same.
```

Above will test for following conditions for both `function` and `coroutine`:

- Normal data
- Data with defect, don't raise error
- Data with defect, raise all errors it encountered

Even with *Exceptions* this will not cancel task, rather it processes all queue.

Output:

```
Test for data [1, 2, 3]:
Sleep 1.71 start
Awake after 1.71
Sleep 1.74 start
Awake after 1.74
Sleep 1.83 start
Awake after 1.83
Normal function: [1, 4, 9]

Coroutine sleep 1.32 start
Coroutine sleep 1.01 start
Coroutine awake after 1.01
Coroutine sleep 1.98 start
Coroutine awake after 1.32
Coroutine awake after 1.98
Coroutine [1, 4, 9]

Test for data [1, 'yo', 3] without raise:
Sleep 1.57 start
Awake after 1.57
Sleep 1.98 start
Awake after 1.98
Sleep 1.39 start
Awake after 1.39
Normal function: [1, TypeError("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"), 9]

Coroutine sleep 1.22 start
Coroutine sleep 2.0 start
Coroutine awake after 1.22
Coroutine sleep 1.96 start
Coroutine awake after 2.0
Coroutine awake after 1.96
Coroutine [1, TypeError("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"), 9]

Test for data [1, 'yo', 3] with raise:
Sleep 1.99 start
Awake after 1.99
Sleep 1.74 start
Awake after 1.74
Sleep 1.52 start
Awake after 1.52
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
line 52, in procedure
    raise Exception(errors)
Exception: [TypeError("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'")]
```

Do note that I've set `concurrent_limit` 2 to demonstrate coroutine waiting for available worker. That's why one *coroutine* task is not running immediately out of 3.

From output you can also see some tasks are finished before others, but results are in order.

---

P.S.

If you're importing `Queue` separately because of PEP-8 line limit violated via type-hint, you can add type-hint as following:

```
async def worker(input_queue, output_queue) -> None:
    input_queue: asyncio.Queue
    output_queue: asyncio.Queue
```

or

```
async def worker(
        input_queue: asyncio.Queue,
        output_queue: asyncio.Queue
    ) -> None:
```

Although it's not as clean as original way, but that will help others reading your code.

Comment: You said that my worker is not catching exceptions, but it's clearly in a try/finally block, so it does inform the queue the task is done whether an exception occurred or not.
I would expect the task to be cancelled at that point though.

Comment: @Jiehong It does inform the queue that the current task is done, but then it _stops processing tasks_. As a result, further tasks enqueued by the producer are not picked up by the worker, nor is `task_done()` called. Since your test code adds the exception raise to all the workers, no one is left to process the items, which blocks `join()` from ever completing.

Comment: @jupiterbjy: ah, I see. It makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @Jiehong ```try - finally``` does not catch error - rather, it *guarantees* you execution of ```finally``` block. ```except``` is what catching error, and allow *worker* to keep working without raising error over entire stack. For ```task_done``` - it should be called as much as ```put```, but it didn't by reason @user4815162342 said. Glad it helped!